# YouTube jhipster4 Blog Demo : where is 'principal' from? it seems no params in the method of the inteface

Tags: jhipster

```
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog,Long> {

    @Query("select blog from Blog blog where blog.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
    List<Blog> findByUserIsCurrentUser();

}
```

where is 'principal' from? it seems no param named principal in the method of the inteface,and so does the domain field.

Answer (score 1):

It's just how SpEL works for spring data JPA. Spring Security adds a few variables to EvaluationContext.

See https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions